# How to choose Columns report

Tags: c#, linq

I want to choose the columns to be displayed in the report ، With this code :

```
 Database1Entities DBE = new Database1Entities();
 string FirstName = "";
 string LastName = "";
 if (checkBoxFirstName.IsChecked == true)
     FirstName = "c.First_Name";
 if (checkBoxLastName.IsChecked == true)
     LastName = "c.Last_Name";

 var search = from c in DBE.Tables
              where
              string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBoxFirstName.Text) || (textBoxFirstName.Text) == (c.First_Name)
              &&
              string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBoxLastName.Text) || (textBoxLastName.Text) == (c.Last_Name)
              select new { FirstName, LastName };
 dataGrid.ItemsSource = search.ToList();
```

But the result is :

[image]

In the above code I've used two variables `FirstName`and `LastName`. If the check box is checked In a report to be displayed , but it does not work.

Comment: `select new { FirstName, LastName }` - You're selecting the literal strings you defined earlier, not the actual values on `c`.  Did you mean `select new { c.FirstName, c.LastName }` ?  It's not really clear what you're trying to do with those values in the first place.

Comment: What is the correct way to do it ?

Comment: The correct way to select data in the query?  Exactly the way I showed in the first comment.  By selecting from the `c` variable in the query.

Comment: This is the correct way And I know it . But can not  By this way choose The columns want displayed in datagridview

Comment: What DataGridView?  Wouldn't that be a UI concern, showing and hiding columns?  I don't see why that would need to be done in the data layer.  Just select the data you want and show/hide columns in the UI as needed.

Comment: You trying to select columns know at runtime only. Use Dynamic LINQ.